# Encrypted LVM logical volume: device-mapper: reload ioctl on test (253:3) failed: Invalid argument

Tags: lvm, luks

I have an LVM volume group in which I already have various logical volumes. In
this volume group, I want to create a new, encrypted, logical volume. I tried
several tutorials (like [this
one](https://www.debuntu.org/how-to-encrypted-partitions-over-lvm-with-luks/)).

I do the following steps:

1. Create the logical volume: `sudo lvcreate -L 50GB -n my_new_lv /dev/my_vg`.
2. Encrypt: `sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/my_vg/my_new_lv`.
3. Map: `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/my_vg/my_new_lv test`.

And I get the following error:

```
Enter passphrase for /dev/my_vg/my_new_lv: 
device-mapper: reload ioctl on test (253:3) failed: Invalid argument
```

Could you help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: The second command should be luksFormat. Please correct your question.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this typo. Fixed.

Comment: Looks like an issue with the kernel: build options, available kernel modules for crypto etc: https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/issues/531 . Are you using a standard distribution with its provided kernel, or is there something special about it (custom-built etc)?

Comment: I am using a Raspberry Pi 4B with standard Raspberry Pi OS based on Debian 11. I don't think I ever configured or modified anything related to the kernel. Is there something I can check?

Comment: You could check for related `dmesg` kernel messages. I don't have any other idea.

Comment: All I can see from `sudo dmesg | less` that looks comparable is those lines:
```
[946077.370602]  __ext4_ioctl+0x82c/0xef0
[946077.370611]  ext4_ioctl+0x2e/0x50
[946077.370618]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x92/0xd0
```